# How do I get Lame

Tags: lame

I downloaded Asunder file converter but an error occurs saying I need to have Lame installed. I went to the Ubuntu Software Center but there is nothing there called Lame. It might be under a different name but I have no clue what it might be. I am running 10.04 Lucid. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu has not been supported for many years, might be time for an update?

Comment: Whoa, 10.04 has been unsupported for years now. Unless you have a reason not to, you should really upgrade to a supported release, such as 14.04 or 15.10. 16.04 is going to be released in a week.

Comment: I love this question title.  It offers so many opportunities.  Like "Dude, 10.04 is already pretty lame." :-p

Answer (score 2):

You'll want the packages `lame`, `twolame`, `libmp3lame0` and `libtwolame0` installed (on most Ubuntu versions the first two will automatically install the second two).

It's likely that these packages were not in the older version of Ubuntu you have.  You need to upgrade, for various reasons.